# How to create a dataframe column combined with multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have some data that tracks the changes of company names over time. However, instead of having each name change on a single row, I would like to have them concatenated all in one field.

The **input** data can be built using:

```
#Import the modules:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create the empty data frame:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dt','old_name','new_name'])

#Populate the data frame:
df.loc[len(df)] = ['01/01/2001', 'AAA', 'BBB']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['02/02/2002', 'BBB', 'CCC']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['03/03/2003', 'CCC', 'DDD']

#View the output:
df
```

How I want the **output** to look like can be created using this:

```
#Create the empty data frame:
end_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dt','name'])

#Populate:
end_df.loc[len(end_df)] = ['01/01/2001', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD']
end_df.loc[len(end_df)] = ['02/02/2002', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD']
end_df.loc[len(end_df)] = ['03/03/2003', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD']

#View the output:
end_df
```

***Edit:*** I am running this code in Pyspark2 using a pandas data frame - in case that makes any difference to the syntax. 
**Also,** there are multiple groups of names in my data set. By this I mean, there are more groups of name changes unrelated to the first group whose names will need to be concatenated.

**Sample Grouped Input:**

```
#Create the empty data frame:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dt','old_name','new_name'])

#Populate the data frame:
df.loc[len(df)] = ['01/01/2001', 'AAA', 'BBB']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['02/02/2002', 'BBB', 'CCC']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['03/03/2003', 'CCC', 'DDD']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['02/01/2001', 'XXX', 'YYY']
df.loc[len(df)] = ['03/02/2002', 'YYY', 'ZZZ']
```

**Sample Grouped Output:**

```
#Create the empty data frame:
end_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dt','name'])

#Populate:
end_df.loc[len(end_df)] = ['01/01/2001', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD']
end_df.loc[len(end_df)] = ['02/02/2002', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD']
end_df.loc[len(end_df)] = ['03/03/2003', 'AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD']
end_df.loc[len(end_df)] = ['02/01/2001', 'XXX-YYY-ZZZ']
end_df.loc[len(end_df)] = ['03/02/2002', 'XXX-YYY-ZZZ']
```

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Why is this tagged `pyspark`? Everything you've shown is `pandas`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I accidentally posted the question when I wasn't yet finished. I will add in the edits now.

Answer (score 4):

you need `np.flatten and np.unique`

```
import numpy as np
end_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dt','name'])
end_df['dt']=df['dt'].copy()
flat=df[df.columns[1:]].values.flatten()
end_df['name']='-'.join(np.unique(flat))

print(end_df)
    dt          name
0   01/01/2001  AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
1   02/02/2002  AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
2   03/03/2003  AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
```

Comment: Hi pyd. thanks for your response. I just edited my question as I forgot to mention that there are multiple groups of name changes within my data set. Besides that, your solution works great!  Would you know how to "group" each of the name changes?

Answer (score 0):

Created two `dicts`: `old_new_dict` to traverse from old to new name and `old_new_dict_rev` to traverse from new to old name :

```
old_new_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(df.old_name,df.new_name)}          
old_new_dict_rev = {v:k for k,v in zip(df.old_name,df.new_name)}
```

Function `find_tree`, traverses in both direction and joins them to create the full path of names.

```
def find_tree(name):
    left_list = []
    right_list = []
    name_l, name_r = name, name

    while(name_l in old_new_dict_rev):
        left_list.append(old_new_dict_rev[name_l])
        name_l = old_new_dict_rev[name_l]
    left_list.reverse()

    while(name_r in old_new_dict):
        right_list.append(old_new_dict[name_r])
        name_r = old_new_dict[name_r]

    return "-".join(left_list + [name] + right_list)
```

Add the full path as `name` column in dataframe `df`:

```
df['name'] = df['old_name'].apply(lambda x: find_tree(x))
end_df = df.drop(['old_name','new_name'], axis = 1)

end_df
#           dt             name
#0  01/01/2001  AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
#1  02/02/2002  AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
#2  03/03/2003  AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
#3  02/01/2001      XXX-YYY-ZZZ
#4  03/02/2002      XXX-YYY-ZZZ
```